# Swift detect external Keyboard key-press

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, keyboard

I´m coding an iOS game (with SpriteKit) and I want to control it with an external Keyboard.
I tried that code:

```
    func DownArrowPress(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
    print("Arrow Down Start")
}
func UpArrowPress(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
    print("Arrow Up Start")
}
func LeftArrowPress(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
    print("Arrow Left Start")
}
func RightArrowPress(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
    print("Arrow Right Start")
}
func SpaceKeyPress(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
    print("Space Start")
}
override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
    return [
        UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyInputDownArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: "DownArrowPress"),
        UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyInputUpArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: "UpArrowPress"),
        UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyInputLeftArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: "UIKeyInputLeftArrow"),
        UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyInputRightArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: "UIKeyInputRightArrow"),
        UIKeyCommand(input: " ", modifierFlags: [], action: "SpaceKeyPress")]
}
```

But now I have two issues:

1. I can't detect the end of the keypress!
2. Nothing happens, if I press a key...

Do you have an idea to fix the issues?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are trying on simulator. Then you have make the simulator receive the events.
This can be done by: Hardware -> Keyboard -> Send Menu Keyboard Shortcuts to Device.